# grub2 password protection does not work with plain text

Tags: grub2

I am using centos 7 and I am trying to configure grub password protection, when using pbkdf2 encryption everything is ok but using plain text password it does not work.  I have taken care of syntax and use the mkconfig tool to replace the grub.conf but still nothing.  Have anyone succeeded with this configuration?,  I know that encrypted passwords is a best practice but I want to have the whole picture.  Please find below my config used, the file /etc/grub.d/01_users:

```
cat <<EOF
set superusers="main"
password main mainpass
password user1 user1pass
EOF
```

Comment: For me, this is not working even with encrypted passwords! I think it is a bug! https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords